# Accessing a git repository via a shared folder on another computer

Tags: git

I have the following scenario: Computer A has access to a git repository, and Computer B has the access to a shared folder on A but no access to the git repository. I would like to push from B to git repository via A.

I am able to do that, but it works in an awkward way. I cloned the repository on A's shared folder, then I cloned the repository from A's shared folder to B. This way I can push/pull from B.

Now if I check changes in A, what I see are code changes relative to B, not the git repository, i.e. if a line has been added on B, I see it on A as the same line removed.

In order to push from A to the git server, I need to first revert all changes and then I can push.
How would I correctly do the process of pushing from B to A, then pushing from A to the git server?

Comment: You can clone / push / fetch between local machines using an ssh connection. if you computer A has the repo in a folder `/path/to/repo`, you can clone that on machine B with `git clone username@machineA:/path/to/repo`. Just make sure you can ssh from B into A with `ssh user@A` first.

Comment: Sharing repository using filesystem functionality works poorly. It is easier just configure some online repo. There are some which are private and free if team is not to big.